# Processing a login from a custom Socialite provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on

I have been following the instructions [here](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/envato/) to install this custom provider for socialite on an install of Laravel 5.3

I am redirected back with an access token and everything within a user object.

I am wondering however what the best way to store that information to authenticate them into the app or if a user doesn't exist to place them into a new one.

Here is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Socialite;
use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Envato authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::with('envato')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Envato.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::with('envato')->user();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I do is create a user entry for them where the email(in case it was not returned from envato) and password are set to null, and create a social_profile entry that belongs to that user, which has his access token and envato id and any extra info.

now there are multiple test cases there... one example is if he signs up later with email/password. you make him validate by email(like reset password).

Comment: I ended up doing it this way in the end. In the handleProviderCallback method i checked email address against current users and if none found then i sent to registration page with name and email address from envato in the session and an error to flash to the screen.I'm sure using another table to store social logins is how i will do it in the future though.

Comment: well you could always check on my answer if it qualifies as correct. just make sure to cover all cases. I had trouble with one of them... you can see it in my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295204/social-login-duplicate-accounts-conflict)